# Django TemplateDoesNotExists in production (only for a single template which exists)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, celery

I know that this question has been asked often before, but no one of other help me to fix my problem.
I'm getting a TemplateDoesNotExists from my Django app running on Elastic Beanstalk, the funny part is that:

1. my django settings are perfectly defined
2. the template exists (I can ssh on my ec2 and see it among the other)
3. in the same folder where the template is not found there is another template that is used successfully
4. by typing `ls -hal` in that folder, I can see that both have the same user/group/permissions:

   > -rw-rw-rw- 1 wsgi root 2.2K Mar 22 16:12 BaseEmailTemplate.html
   >
   > -rw-rw-rw- 1 wsgi root  312 Mar 22 16:12 DefaultNewsletterTemplate.html
5. on my local machine I have no issues ("works on my machine" TM :D)

Now, the particularity of that template (**DefaultNewsletterTemplate.html**) is that is being loaded "manually" using `loader.get_template`:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
get_template('the_app/the_template.html')
```

since I use it to render my newsletter in a Celery task... but once again the same happens for the **BaseEmailTemplate.html** which is used for each email communication (**DefaultNewsletterTemplate.html** extends it)... so what's going on??? What should I try to do?

Comment: So... I can't really say what's the problem becuase you hardly shared anything (for starters, share your `settings.py`, templates and relevant views. Even if they are "perfectly defined", maybe you still overlooked something). But I can say that it seems like the problem is probably with `BaseEmailTemplate.html` (and the other one receives the same error because it extends it).

Comment: Also, don't name your templates `FooBarTemplate`. That's a bad naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
It turned out, that the problem was related to the user used by Celery (and managed by Supervisor) that had not the right privileges. Using root user works perfectly!